# What is a synonym for “I should have, but I didn’t”

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

E.g (2):

I should have stopped him before it was too late, but I didn’t

I should have provided a source, but i didn’t.

I am looking for a single word for the entire sentence; a synonym. I’m not looking for the word “regret”, but something sort of alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**failed**

> to not do something that you should do

[fail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fail)

So your sentences could be:

*I failed to provide a source.*

*I failed to stop him.* or

*I failed him.*

Bonus answer: neglected

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: “Neglected” was just the right answer i was looking for.